# Is there a way to prevent a backslash ('\\') from reduplicating to '\\\\'?

Tags: python, syntax, zip, backslash

I have a regular structure of archives with the format `pathtofile\folder.zip`, and I need to access a file within each archive with the format ```folder\image.png`.

The code I am using to achieve this is:

```
import zipfile
imgname = path[:-4].split('\\')[-1] + '\\image.png'
imgfile = archive.extract(imgname, path=dst)`
```

Where `path = pathtofile\\folder.zip`

However this is throwing the error below:

`KeyError: "There is no item named 'folder\\\\image.png' in the archive"`

I have also tried removing the `\\` from the `imgname` definition, but this throws the following error:

`KeyError: "There is no item named 'folderimage.png' in the archive"`

so it seems like the backslashes really are reduplicating themselves somehow.

I'm wondering what could be causing the backslashes to multiply; if anyone has any wise words they would be greatly appreciated!

Larger part of the code:

```
archives = dict()

sub_data = data['file_path']    # data is a pandas dataframe containing file names and data about each file
filenames = get_unique(list(sub_data))    # get_unique is equivalent to list(set(sequence))

for filename in filenames:
    zip_path = image_dir+filename+'.zip'
    fil = sub_data == filename
    frames = [f for f in data.loc[fil, 'local_index']]
    archives.update({zip_path: frames})

keys = list(archives.keys())

for i in range(len(filenames)):
    key = keys[i]
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(key, 'r')
    dst = output_image_dir+'\\'+filenames[i]    # output_image_dir is a filepath not ending in '\\'
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    for frame in archives[key]:
        imgname = os.path.join(key[:-4].split('\\')[-1], 'frame'+str(frame).zfill(7)+'.png')
        if not os.path.exists(dst+'\\'+imgname):
            imgfile = archive.extract(imgname, path=dst)
```

Comment: If you `print(repr(imgname))` before `archive.extract`, what does it show?

Comment: Use the functions provided in [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: I would recommend using [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and change your code to `os.path.join(path[:-4].split('\\')[-1], 'image.png')`

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you can post the full code

Comment: When I run `print(repr(imgname))` it prints out the expected result with only two backslashes instead of four .

I run into the exact same problem when I use `os.path.join()` as when I just use string addition (although the join function is certainly cleaner)

Comment: Not just clearer; it will also work across different OS-es, whereas code in your style would not.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't actually solve my problem, although I greatly appreciate the learning moment =D. Any other ideas as to what could cause it? Could it be something within the zipfile module?